# unicode character doesnot shown in browser

Tags: unicode, character

In header section I have set

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

and `lang="ne-np"` is also set .

But while rendering on browser, Unicode character is converted to English character as shown in picture here.

[image: character in console not rendered on page]

Used bootstrap 4, jQuery 3.5.1

As like character shown in console, I need to render in on page. any help please.

note: actual character are : `२०७७-०४-२०`, but displayed character are: `2077-04-20`

Comment: Hi, could you please add the actual characters into the question? Thank you.

Comment: Finally got the solution: in my case, google font "Poppins", sans-serif" was playing role... using different font helped me.